# Spawn strings instead of objects on JsonServer.io

Tags: json, api, backend, spawn, faker

I'm using the [JsonServer.io](https://www.jsonserver.io/) to mock my backend API, but I struggle with the spawn of string values. Is there a possibility to do this? I managed it to spawn one or more objects, but in my usecase I have to spawn string values instead.

I would expect to get a result like this:

```
"categories": [
    "category-one",
    "category-two",
    "category-three",
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For spawning a property as array by its value, your have to do a similar expression like to spawn objects, just use it behind the value you need instead of using it at property name.

```
"categories": "expression|spawn(5)"
```

This will generate the expected array.

Answer (score 1):

You can also visit the official [documentation](https://www.jsonserver.io/docs/) for more detailed information.